# Django filter by many to many with exact same query

Tags: django, many-to-many

Is there any way in django to filter objects with many to many relation by query set or ids list. Get query with exactly same values in many to many.
model

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child, blank=True)
```

views

```
def filter_parents(request):
    children = Child.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(child=child)
    return parents
```

expected:
I am looking for filtered parents with exact same children in many to many field

Comment: Please confirm, you want to get queryset of `Parents` that have same children in `child` field? Like `[Parent(name='1', child='10'), Parent(name='2', child='10'), Parent(name='3', child='20'), Parent(name='4', child='20'), ]` Like a queryset of `Parents` whoes children has at list 2 Parents, yes?

Comment: @SergeyPugach yeah, some children have 2 parents and some parents have several children (like 2 or more). I have query set of children (filtered by names or ids or ages).
And need to get Parents with exact same many to many record.

Comment: @SergeyPugach I mean not geting parents by _set, but filter them by many to many field

Comment: So you need Parents who have at least 2 children and those who children are in your queryset `children` right?

Comment: @SergeyPugach right, but with a little fix, there may be 1 or 4 children, the amount is dynamic.
`Child.objects.filter(id__in=request.GET.get('ids_list', ''))`

Comment: So you need to get Parents who have exactly same childens that are listed in `children` queryset? I mean if you have `children` for `[1,2,3]` ids, so you need parents who have exactly `[1,2,3]` children? Sorry for a lot of questions, the task is to clear from the start.

Comment: @SergeyPugach, yes, you got the problem right :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use chain filtering for that case.

```
from django.db.models import Count

children_id_list = [1, 2, 3]
parents = Parent.objects.annotate(count=Count('children')).filter(count=len(children_id_list))

for child_id in children_id_list:
    parents = parents.filter(children__id=child_id)
```

Or you can use lambda filtering:

```
c_id_list = [1, 2, 3]
parents = Parent.objects.annotate(count=Count('children')).filter(count=len(children_id_list))
parents = reduce(lambda p, id: parents.filter(child=id), c_id_list, parents)
```

Or you can use `Q()` query:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

children_id_list = [1, 2, 3]
parents = Parent.objects.annotate(count=Count('children')).filter(count=len(children_id_list))

query = Q()
for child_id in children_id_list:
    query &= Q(children__id=child_id)
parents = parents.filter(query)
```

As a result you will get only `Parent` objects who have all those `children` in your list of ids only no less no more.

Comment: yeah... this solution looks like a crunch but also I can't find more elegant solution(s). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
parents = Parent.objects.filter(children__id__in=[1,2,3])
```

**UPDATE:**

I think you need to `unpack` the child Ids and then do the following.

```
parents = Parent.objects.annotate(child_id=F('children__id'))
                        .filter(child__id__in=[1,2,3])
                        .order_by('email').distinct('email')
```

Please note that the `order_by` is necessary here as not having it would break the `distinct` operation. Note that you should replace the `email` with the field that's unique in your `User` model.

This should accomplish exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: nope. look, this code is going to show parents even with children__id = [1,2,3,4,5,9]
I need parent with exactly same children, no more

Comment: Oh. So you're looking to match all 3 children then?

Comment: You don't have the ids of children and you wanna get pairs of parents who have same children?

Comment: I got children ids, `Child.objects.filter(id__in=request.GET.get('ids_list', ''))`. And need parents with exactly that children.
Btw, there can be even more than 2 parents in case if children were adopted