# How to filter deeper in objects in django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to filter on the fruit type in my django project. The problem is that I use many objects and the last one needs to get filtert.

Here is an example of the structure.
[image: problem]

So I would like that my inputs only show the plots that are manytomany that have the fruit pear for example.

I tried the following code to see what path I had to get to the fruit:

```py
Input.objects.get(pk=1).plot.get(pk=1).Fruittype.fruit
```

this returns:

```py
<Fruit: pear>
```

So this is the correct path but I don't know how i can filter all the objects to the fruit.

Sorry if it is unclear what I mean, but this is not my native language.
Edit: this is what i would like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFYtt.jpg

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what objects you want. The `Input`s?

Comment: I would like the 'input's filtert with the plots(which are also many to many) that have the fruit 'pear' for example

Comment: when I say `input.objects.filter(plot__fruittype__fruit__vrucht="Pear")[0].plot.all()` I get `QuerySet [<Plot: Pear | testperceel1>, <Plot: Apple | testpreceel2>, <Plot: Apple | Testperceel3>]>`

Comment: You want all the inputs that contains ONLY "Pear" and not those that contains ALSO Pear amongst other? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: yes, I would only like to have the ones with pear, so that I can filter on the fruit

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are ways to make it better, but this does what you want.

```
pear = Fruit.objects.get(name="pear") #  "name" or whatever property name you used
Input.objects.annotate(c=Count('plot__fruittype')).filter(c=1, plot__fruittype=pear)
```

It won't work if you're searching for exact equivalence with more than 1 fruittype. If you need that feature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53911762/1307020

Comment: Oke thanks, I only get the plots where only one plot with the fruit Pear was, I would also like to have the others but only with the pears visible...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. Can you make an example of the output you want?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UPP3oFf here you can find some images of what i want ;)

Comment: I tried he following: 
```plots = Plot.objects.filter(fruittype__fruit="pears")

all_inputs = Input.objects.filter(plot__in=plots).distinct()```
which gives me the only the inputs where pears are, but the inputs were pears and apples are still show up...